# WPML admin texts with serialized objects

Tags: array, translation, localization, options, plugin-wpml

I have been trying to get a plugin to work with WPML - I'm almost there but I'm wondering if anyone knows if it's possible to get WPML's admin texts (wpml-config.xml) to read serialized objects stored in wp_options?

Ref: https://wpml.org/documentation/support/language-configuration-files/

It works with arrays fine, but I cannot get it to pick up objects.

Below is a sample of what I'm trying to get it to read:

```
s:13:"custom_fields";a:4:{i:0;O:8:"stdClass":7:{s:9:"field_key";s:10:"bama_multi";s:10:"field_name";s:5:"Multi";s:10:"field_type";s:11:"multiselect";s:13:"default_value";s:0:"";s:14:"show_on_signup";b:1;s:8:"required";b:1;s:7:"options";a:3:{i:0;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:11:"option_name";s:3:"One";s:12:"option_value";s:3:"one";}i:1;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:11:"option_name";s:3:"Two";s:12:"option_value";s:3:"two";}i:2;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:11:"option_name";s:5:"Three";s:12:"option_value";s:5:"three";}}}i:1;O:8:"stdClass":7:{s:9:"field_key";s:13:"bama_dropdown";s:10:"field_name";s:8:"Dropdown";s:10:"field_type";s:8:"dropdown";s:13:"default_value";s:0:"";s:14:"show_on_signup";b:1;s:8:"required";b:1;s:7:"options";a:3:{i:0;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:11:"option_name";s:3:"Uno";s:12:"option_value";s:3:"uno";}i:1;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:11:"option_name";s:3:"Dos";s:12:"option_value";s:3:"dos";}i:2;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:11:"option_name";s:4:"Tres";s:12:"option_value";s:4:"tres";}}}i:2;O:8:"stdClass":7:{s:9:"field_key";s:15:"bama_checkboxes";s:10:"field_name";s:10:"Checkboxes";s:10:"field_type";s:10:"checkboxes";s:13:"default_value";s:0:"";s:14:"show_on_signup";b:1;s:8:"required";b:1;s:7:"options";a:3:{i:0;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:11:"option_name";s:1:"E";s:12:"option_value";s:1:"e";}i:1;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:11:"option_name";s:1:"R";s:12:"option_value";s:1:"r";}i:2;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:11:"option_name";s:3:"San";s:12:"option_value";s:3:"san";}}}i:3;O:8:"stdClass":7:{s:9:"field_key";s:11:"bama_radios";s:10:"field_name";s:6:"Radios";s:10:"field_type";s:6:"radios";s:13:"default_value";s:0:"";s:14:"show_on_signup";b:1;s:8:"required";b:1;s:7:"options";a:3:{i:0;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:11:"option_name";s:1:"A";s:12:"option_value";s:1:"a";}i:1;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:11:"option_name";s:1:"B";s:12:"option_value";s:1:"b";}i:2;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:11:"option_name";s:1:"C";s:12:"option_value";s:1:"c";}}}}
```

It's an array of standard objects, and I'd like to make the field_name's and option_name's translatable.

I know I can change the custom_fields to use arrays instead of objects, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Any ideas - or is this strictly a limitation of WPML?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to switch to arrays instead of objects. Even that hasn't worked out as well as I hoped.